# Discord.js Quick.db filter

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, quick.db

Hi ive been trying to make a filter for my Discord.js bot that you can do .add (word) and it will start filtering that specific word but when i try it only does 1 word not multiple

```
if(command === "filteradd"){
       if(message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES'))

   if(!args[0]) {
       let color = message.member.displayHexColor;
       if(!color) color = "RANDOM";
       const sen = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       .setTitle(`${message.author.tag}`)
       .setDescription(`Send a word to filter`)
       .setColor(color)
       return message.channel.send(sen)
     } 

   

     
     db.add(`badword_${message.guild.id}`, args[0])
     let color = message.member.displayHexColor;
     if(!color) color = "RANDOM";
     const set = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle("Succesfully added")
     .setColor(color)
   await message.channel.send(set)
     
   
   
}
```

and then

```
client.on("message", async message => {
  
    if(message.author.bot) return;
      if(!message.guild) return;
      let blacklisted = db.get(`badword_${message.guild.id}`)
            
         if (!message.member) message.member = message.guild.fetchMember(message);


    let foundInText = false;
    for (var i in blacklisted) {
      if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(blacklisted[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText = true;
    }
    if (foundInText) {
      message.delete();
      message.channel.send(`yo this actually worked wtf`);
    }
    });
```

any help would be appreciated!`enter code here`

Answer (score -1):

You are still using `args[0]` as your method for getting the blacklisted words, you can't do this if you want to have multiple arguments.

Use a `for` loop, and iterate through the arguments:

```js
if (args[1]) { //checks for multiple arguments
   let badWordArr = args; //mirrors the args array 

   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < badWordArr.Length(); i++) {
      db.add(`badword_${message.guild.id}`, args[i]); //as the loop increments, the words are added
   }
};

//additional code here
```